# How to add a months to a timestamp with time zone value while keeping the exact same hour

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone, oracle18c

I have a PL/SQL variable of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to whose value I want to add exactly one month.
But especially the time should remain identical when changing from daylight saving time to standard time.

The following `SELECT` (although not PLS/SQL) shows the problem:

```sql
WITH
   data
   AS
      (    SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-04-17 05:00:00 EUROPE/BERLIN', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr') + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(LEVEL, 'MONTH') AS ts
             FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7)
SELECT to_char(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr') AS ts
  FROM data;
```

This returns

```
2023-05-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-06-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-07-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-08-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-09-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-10-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin
2023-11-17 04:00:00 Europe/Berlin
```

As you can see the time changes to 4 o'clock in November.

Is there a function in Oracle to add a month without changing the time?

Comment: Use an interval e.g. UPDATE MY_TABLE SET mytsz = mytsz + INTERVAL '1' MONTH

Comment: When using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then all date math functions are done on UTC times. So, it is not trivial.

Comment: I'm afraid problem is withing daylight saving time, and from time perspective `2023-10-17 05:00:00 Europe/Berlin` and  `2023-11-17 04:00:00 Europe/Berlin` are exactly 1 month apart.

Comment: If you really-really want to get same hours in your result, you'll need to work with parts of dates as with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
FROM_TZ(
   CAST(
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-04-17 05:00:00 EUROPE/BERLIN', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr') AS TIMESTAMP
   ) + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(LEVEL, 'MONTH'),
   'Europe/Berlin'
)
```

`CAST(... AS TIMESTAMP)` removes the time zone (and DST) information, then it adds the months and afterwards you attach time zone again with `FROM_TZ`

Comment: This [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/7OoG84Ry). Could you explain why it works?)

Comment: Wernfried, thank you!

Comment: Looks promising , but `EUROPE/BERLIN` was just an example. I would need to somehow extract the timezone from the given value, to be able to add it back later.

Comment: Then you need to extract the timezone from input/column value with `TO_CHAR(..., 'tzr')` or `EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_REGION FROM ...)`